# Is it possible to customize metadata of a parquet file?

Tags: python, metadata, parquet

As I know the parquet file has 2 parts: Data and metadata. The metadata is split into a header and a footer, which are generated information.

So can I customize the header or the footer to add some information? If yes, how?

I need the customized metadata to be embedded in the file.

Thank you